# Custom node Template for script tags

Tags: theming

I wanted to add script code to implement "LiveChat" functionality on just three pages of our website. So, I wanted to add one script code given by our LiveChat agency into three webpages of our website.

**Script Code**

```
<script src="http://www.examp.com/scripts/invitation.ashx?company=4444"></script>
```

So, I have created three separate html node templates based on their node ID.

Theses three custom node templates are under

**/sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates** along with (***node.tpl.php and html.tpl.php***)

1. (**contact page**) html--node--28.tpl.php

**Url of this page:** www.example.com/contact

2. (**admissions page**) html--node--1212.tpl.php

**Url of this page:** www.example.com/admissions

3. (**market page**) html--node--378.tpl.php

**Url of this page:** www.example.com/market

Code used in all custom node templates (html--node--28.tpl.php, html--node--1212.tpl.php, html--node--378.tpl.php) is the same:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>"<?php print $rdf_namespaces; ?>>
<head profile="<?php print $grddl_profile; ?>">
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
  <?php print $styles; ?>
 </head>
<body<?php print $attributes;?>>
<?php print $scripts; ?>
//Adding script for LiveChat
<script src="http://www.examp.com/scripts/invitation.ashx?company=4444"></script>
  <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable"><?php print t('Skip to main content'); ?></a>
  </div>
  <?php print $page_top; ?>
  <?php print $page; ?>
  <?php print $page_bottom; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

But, I am not able to see my script (`<script src="http://www.examp.com/scripts/invitation.ashx?company=4444"></script>`) when I debugged it in view pagesource.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to double check cus you didn't mention doing it, did you clear you cache after adding these template files?

Comment: Yes, I have cleared cache

Comment: If you make a change to your html.tpl.php file in that containing folder, do your other pages get changed? And do these pages change?

Comment: Yes, if I add this <script> code into my html.tpl.php file then I can see changes in all the pages. But, if I add this script in three node id pages, then I am not able to see any change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding three template files for three nodes with the same content in it in my opinion will be a better solution to add the JS file conditionally using `drupal_add_js`

For eg:

```
 $allowed_nid = array(28, 1212, 38);
 if(in_array(arg(1), $allowed_nid)){
  drupal_add_js("http://www.examp.com/scripts/invitation.ashx?company=4444", "external");
 }
```

You can add the snippet in a `hook_init` function in any of your custom modules. (Best is add in a custom utility module which hold all general function to be used throughout.)
Else you can add it in your theme's `template.php` in the `template_preprocess_page` function.

Comment: Thanks Malabya .. Where should I add this function? Should I add it in template.php file?

Comment: @Vidushi Have updated the answer with it. :)

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks. Instead of just three nodes, Can we make it available for under entire 'Admissions' sections? I mean all the subpages of 'Admissions' section?

Comment: What do you mean by subpages? As per my understanding from your question its better to have 3 separate pages.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But, now my client wants it on all the admissions pages as well. If 2.0 Admissions, 2.1 - About admissions, 2.1.2 - Contact us, 2.1.3,2.1.4, 2.3,2.4... So, all the subpages of Admissions along with three different pages.

Comment: OK. So they will be separate pages then just add the nid of the pages in the `$allowed_nid` array

Comment: There are more than 50 pages under admissions, so is there any other way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24765/discussion-between-malabya-tewari-and-vidushi).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to your `html.tpl.php`

```
<?php $node = menu_get_object();
      if ($node && $node->nid == NID):?>

<script>
<--! Your script goes here -->
</script>

<?php endif;?>
```